# DeDupe: Prefix with and without period

Tags: duplicate-contacts

Seems I've got tons of dedupe hits on prefixes with and without periods, ie, "Dr" vs "Dr."

Any advice on how to deal with this? Was this from various schema updates over the years?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by 'dedupe hits'? Do you have two contact records for people, one with Dr and one with Dr.? If you look in your 'Individual Prefixes' options do you have both 'Dr' and 'Dr.' as options? The easiest way to fix this is to choose the prefix you prefer and perform a bulk update (probably in the DB) to change them. If I've understood the issue correctly then I'll post that as an answer.

Comment: Agree with John's option. Otherwise, are you using a Dedupe Rule that includes Prefix? Could you set it to be only 2 characters in length, this might help you avoid some of them if that is your goal.

Comment: Do you really need to include prefix?  It seems unlikely you'd have a Dr. John Smith and a John Smith that have the same address or email or phone number or whatever other matching data.  It seems more likely to have the same exact person with and without a prefix, which wouldn't be caught by including prefix.  BTW the sql to fix them all to have the "correct" prefix is pretty trivial.  If you want it, ask.